# Tempo problem in Schubert D784, 2nd movement

Tags: notation, tempo, interpretation

I am studying Schubert Sonata in a-minor D784. I have a problem with the tempo in the 2nd movement.

In my scores (Wiener Urtext, thus, I suppose this is not a typo) the 2nd movement is written in *Alla Breve* with tempo marking *Andante*.
To my feeling the Andante is only possible with respect to the quarter note and **not** with respect to the half note -- which it should be since the piece is in *Alla Breve*.

Since Schubert is quite "exact" with his tempo markings (e.g. first movement of the sonata is clearly in 4/4, although one could easily think it should be in 2/2, or Schubert Op. 90, D. 899, Gb major with the *double-alla-breve* tempo), I am not fully convinced that the Andante feeling is with respect to the quarter note in this movement.

Does anybody have any ideas about this?

Comment: I understand and share the sense of dilemma. All of the recordings I consulted played it as a quarter-note andante -- at the *fastest*. Some were even slower. But thus far I haven't found any specific justification.

Comment: I guess the problem derives from identifying *Andante* with some 90 beats per (whichever) note instead of a target character for the movement with considerable leeway in every direction. Considering tempo specifications as left hand side of a conversion table for BPM will simply not work for all cases.

Comment: @guidot Andante means "walking". I nowhere identified it with 90bpm.

Comment: Can you produce a convincing interpretation at (for example) half note =90? If not, you've answered your own question.

Comment: @PiedPiper That's exactly the question: OP can't produce a convincing andante interpretation at that speed and is wondering about the seeming contradiction between Schubert's markings, which are otherwise very specific, and the actual effective musical interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Schubert has a number of other very slow Andantes.  The first piano trio has an Andante un poco mosso in 6/8 which is usually played around 44 dotted quarters per minute or slower.  The second trio has an Andante con moto in 2/4 which is usually played around 50 quarter notes per minute at the fastest.

Andante as "walking" (which is spurious anyway) refers to a step every half-beat, or a left foot every beat.

I would play D784 at around 56 half notes per minute, thinking of the half note as the pulse.  This is faster than usual, but I think Schubert slow movements are generally played too slow.  (There is an early music movement influence here; one argument for a faster tempo is that the fortepianos of Schubert's day (even the London action rather than Vienna action ones) articulate faster and sustain notes for less time than a modern piano.)

Comment: Can you give sources for the "'walking' is spurious" and "step every half-beat" comments? These contradict what I've previously understood to be common knowledge, so I'd like to read further.

Comment: "Walking is spurious": https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/53339/andante-assai-usual-interpretation

Comment: Relying on an SE post that is itself undocumented is a dubious way to question a long-established norm. According to the *Oxford Companion to Music*, which is widely considered authoritative, Andante has had an accepted *musical* meaning of "between adagio and allegro" since the late 1700s. (It also attributes the term to Italian, and translates as "walking".) This is otherwise a +1 post, but IMO the sentence about the meaning and interpretation of "andante" should be removed unless you can more solidly back it up.

Comment: "Step every half-beat": That's what I learned.  Certainly there are a lot of andantes where this is the only sensible interpretation - for example the Schubert trios I mentioned or second movement of Mozart K283 or K333 would be unplayable at walking quarters (unless you walked really slowly).  Or Brahms Op. 118 No. 6 - the indication of 'andante, largo e mesto' makes no sense unless you have the main beat every 2 steps.

Comment: @Aaron - yes andante is "between adagio and allegro" and "at a walking tempo", but the attribution to Italian is not backed up by any actual usage in Italian outside of music - every source I've seen discussing this points out there are essentially zero (historical or current) non-musical uses of the word 'andante' in Italian.

Comment: Nevertheless, it's the accepted *musical* definition. I think your post is much stronger if you take out questioning the term and make clear that the 1-beat-equals-2-steps interpretation is how you were taught, rather than presenting it as an accepted interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

The consensus among various recorded versions I've just researched is that it's quarter note Andante.